# How to recover password without restart

Tags: password, password-recovery, recovery-mode

So I recently installed Ubuntu on this computer, I just started using it today for the 2nd time, I needed to install some video plugins to use for the web and it asked me for a password.

I *do not remember ever setting a password during installation*, and I am *not asked for a password to login* either. As far as I knew I never had a password before, is there a way to recover the user password *from within ubuntu* without entering into recovery mode?

I do not see why I need to restart as I never need a password to start up the computer and log in...

Answer (score 1):

When it asks for a password just press enter.

This happens because the system has been coded to function without a password being expected even if the password is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set a password and it is prompting for one to install software then just hit ok / enter and leave the password field blank.  Otherwise you did set a password for your user id.  If this is the case then you have to reset it

I found this to help you.
[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the password is hashed with a salt, making very difficult to brute force it. In such case I'd reset it instead of trying to "decrypt" it.

Another thing to notice is that root does not have password, but instead, your username has sudo privileges, meaning that you can become root by executing "sudo su" command from terminal.